# showing same value of a variable in instances of class in python

Tags: python

i have some problems with writing following program by python:
Write a program to design a class that has the following information
1.Master's number
2.Teacher's name and surname
3.teaching The amount paid per hour
Then, using this, write a program to provide the list of teacher with their salaries.
Then teachers should be presented who have the same salary, and if their salaries are not the same, they should be leveled or grouped

here is my code:

```
class user:
    a=[]
    b=[]
    def __init__(self,teachername="undefiend",teacherfamily="undefiend",teachersalary=0):
        self.un1=teachername
        self.uf1=teacherfamily
        self.ua1=teachersalary
   
    def showinfo(self) :
     
      return f" {self.un1}{self.uf1}{self.ua1 }"

#==============================================================================
    def  salarycomp2(self,teachername):
      if self.ua1<15000:
        user.a.append(teachername)      
      else :
        user.b.append(teachername)        

#================================================================================
    def salarycomp(self,other) :
        if self.ua1==other.ua1:
            print("yes")
        else:
            user.salarycomp2()


tt=user("sara","alae",30000)    
hhh=user("jack","parkor",300000)    
gg=user("mikel","ebel",20000) 
ff=user("daya","eskafi",10000)    
print(tt.showinfo())
print(hhh.showinfo())
print(gg.showinfo())
print(ff.showinfo())
user.salarycomp()
```

errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\SONY\Desktop\New folder\first.py", line 36, in <module>
    user.salarycomp()
TypeError: salarycomp() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'other'
```

Comment: `salarycomp()` is a method and it should be called on objects like `tt`,`hhh` etc. Also it requires another parameter which is also an object of class `user`

Comment: i edited my code but now it does not know( ua1 )in (other.ua1) and when i want to give (other) as a argument to salarycomp() it does not accept. here is link : sololearn.com/compiler-playground/c85F3xABLO34

Comment: from the code in the link I can see that you are still calling `salarycomp()` without any valid object. Also the parameter passed in that method (i.e. `other`) is also not defined. I think you should consult a good book on python for this

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a value for other in the salarycomp() call. you can't invoke a function without a parameter, when you defined for a parameter to be called.

Comment: i edited my code but now it does not know( ua1 )in (other.ua1) and when i want to give (other) as a argument to salarycomp() it does not accept.
here is link :
https://www.sololearn.com/compiler-playground/c85F3xABLO34

Answer (score 0):

You must call a member function from an object not from class, for example:

```
gg.salarycomp(ff)
```

Same must write in `salarycomp` definition:

```
self.salarycomp2(other)
```

instead of `user.salarycomp2()`. It compare current user instead for example with user passed to member function `salarycomp`.

Comment: i edited my code but now it does not know( ua1 )in (other.ua1) and when i want to give (other) as a argument to salarycomp() it does not accept.
here is link :
https://www.sololearn.com/compiler-playground/c85F3xABLO34